# Show that for almost all $x$ in $[-1,1]$, the series $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n \sqrt{|x-r_n|}} $ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $\{r_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers in $[-1, 1]$, then show that for almost all $x$ in $[-1,1]$, the series $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n \sqrt{|x-r_n|}}
> $$ converges.

I am struggling on this problem of real analysis. I know that somehow I have to use the monotone convergence theorem. But I cannot see it clearly. How to get started?

Comment: Hint: Integrate the function and use the fact that a nonnegative function with finite integral is almost everywhere finite.

Comment: @Did Something which is not obvious for me. Why is the function integrable?

Comment: ? Because its integral on $(-1,1)$ is finite. Did you try to compute the integral, or at least an upper bound?

Comment: Good point! I was too lazy to compute it. Shame on me!

Comment: @Did And you use monotone convergence theorem I imagine?